# Connect-MsolService does not work after enabling MFA?

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm trying to run a script to add some users into Office 365.

I am using the following commands to connect via the Microsoft Exchange Online PowerShell Module:

```
Install-Module MSOnline -Scope CurrentUser
Connect-EXOPSSession -UserPrincipalName myname@domain.com
Connect-MsolService
```

I get the following error:

```
Connect-MsolService : An error occurred while sending the request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-MsolService
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], HttpRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectM
   solService
```

However, I am able to run the Get-Mailbox command to run successfully so I know I am connected but nothing else works.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running this directly from Powershell? As if you have not disabled your MFA on your Admin Account this will no longer work. You can go into Azure > Conditional Access and Disable MFA on your account, but I wouldn't recommend it.

You will need to download the MFA PowerShell through your Office365 Portal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/mfa-connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps

Also something else I ran into once MFA was enabled I noticed I could no longer import any modules from https://www.powershellgallery.com , there is way's to fix it, but you can find that information on Microsoft. Also update your MSOnline and Azure AD Module.